# Viewholder with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a new to Android development.  I'm developing a simple application which reads barcode. I have a little problem with adapter and fragment.

I have an adapter class and a fragment class. In the adapter I use ViewHolder class and I'm not able to use my function which check if barcode was scanned and add the item (if barcode is valid) in another list.

My adapter class has this code:

```
 private Context context;   

List<ProdottiList> mItems;
public static int mCaller;                  
public static int IDDocumento;             
public static TBLSOGGETTI mSoggetto;      
public static int mAvanzamentoDoc;         

public static int AdapterMode = MethodsProducts.kAdapterModeList; 

public static ProductsAdapter savedAdapter;  

private static ListView mListView;
public static int IDProdotto = 0;
public static int myPosition = 0;
public static ViewHolder holder;           
public static List<OmaggiList> list1;
public static View mProductView;           
public static View finalMProductView1;      
public static DocumentiRigheList row;       

public ProductsAdapter(Context context, int listview_products_item, List<ProdottiList> listProdottiFiltered, int itemMenuCatalog, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);     


}

public ProductsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ProdottiList> items, int caller, int idDocumento, TBLSOGGETTI soggetto, int AvanzamentoDoc, ListView listView) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.mItems = items;
    this.context = context;
    this.mCaller = caller;
    this.IDDocumento = idDocumento;
    this.mSoggetto = soggetto;
    this.mAvanzamentoDoc = AvanzamentoDoc;       
    this.mListView = listView;
}

public static void saveAdapter(ProductsAdapter item)
{
    savedAdapter = item;
}

public static class ViewHolder {


    public TextView txtNome;        
    public TextView txtQuantita;      
    public TextView txtTotale;

    public Button btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita;
    public Button btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita; 

    public ImageButton imgCarello;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final MySQLiteManager db = new MySQLiteManager(context);

   mProductView = convertView;

    if (mProductView == null) {


        if (mAvanzamentoDoc == DocumentsFragment.StatoDocumentoBozza)
        {
            mProductView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_products_item_qta, parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            mProductView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_products_item, parent, false);
        }


        holder = new ViewHolder();       


        holder.txtNome = (TextView) mProductView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);

        holder.txtQuantita = (TextView) mProductView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantita);           

        holder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita = (Button) mProductView.findViewById(R.id.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita);
        holder.btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita = (Button) mProductView.findViewById(R.id.btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita);
        holder.btnQuantitaSelezionata = (Button) mProductView.findViewById(R.id.btnQuantitaSelezionata);          

        holder.imgCarello = (ImageButton) mProductView.findViewById(R.id.imgCarello);          

        mProductView.setTag(holder);
    }      

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) mProductView.getTag(); //I NEED TO PASS IT

    final ProdottiList product = getItem(position);

    if (product.prodotto != null) {

        final View finalMProductView = mProductView;
        finalMProductView1 = mProductView;

        db.close();


        viewHolder.txtNome.setTag(mProductView);

        viewHolder.txtNome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_APERTO_BOZZA)    
                {) {

                    MethodsProducts.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantitaClick(context, viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita, viewHolder.btnQuantitaSelezionata, position, getItem(position), AdapterMode, savedAdapter, null, mSoggetto, mAvanzamentoDoc, IDDocumento, list);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_MOSTRA_CARRELLO)    //sono nel carrello. Ogni click e una rimozione
                {
                    MethodsProducts.btnRimuoviUnitaQuantitaClick(context, viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita, viewHolder.btnQuantitaSelezionata, position, getItem(position), AdapterMode, savedAdapter, null, mSoggetto, mAvanzamentoDoc, IDDocumento, list);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita.setTag(mProductView);
        viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MethodsProducts.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantitaClick(context, viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita, viewHolder.btnQuantitaSelezionata, position, getItem(position), AdapterMode, savedAdapter, null, mSoggetto, mAvanzamentoDoc, IDDocumento, list);

                if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_MOSTRA_CARRELLO) {
                    Log.d(ClassName, "btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita.setOnClickListener - Sono nel carrello - chiamo il notifyDataSetChanged()");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_APERTO_BOZZA) {
                    if (HomeActivity.agente.getFlagModQtaInCarrello() == 1) {
                        Log.d(ClassName, "btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita.setOnClickListener - Sono nel carrello - chiamo il notifyDataSetChanged()");
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }
        });          
        viewHolder.btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita.setTag(mProductView);
        viewHolder.btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MethodsProducts.btnRimuoviUnitaQuantitaClick(context, viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita, viewHolder.btnQuantitaSelezionata, position, getItem(position), AdapterMode, savedAdapter, null, mSoggetto, mAvanzamentoDoc, IDDocumento, list);

                if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_MOSTRA_CARRELLO) {

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_APERTO_BOZZA) {
                    if (HomeActivity.agente.getFlagModQtaInCarrello() == 1) {
                        Log.d(ClassName, "btnRimuoviUnitaQuantita.setOnClickListener - Sono nel carrello - chiamo il notifyDataSetChanged()");
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });          

        MethodsProducts.SettingDetailOrderRow(context, mCaller, mProductView, product, IDDocumento, 1, position, mSoggetto, mAvanzamentoDoc, list);


        new setRowProductAsync(context, mProductView, position, viewHolder, product, mSoggetto, IDDocumento, mAvanzamentoDoc, list, row).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
     }


    return mProductView;
}
```

And this is my function used in my fragment class to make a confirm dialog when article was found and to add it. I'm using it in the "onCreateView":

```
  public void OpenConfirmDialog()
{
    if (!ProductsFragment2.getPreviousWindow()) {

        if (_barcode != "") {

            MySQLiteManager db = new MySQLiteManager(getActivity());
            String articleName = db.GetProductDescriptionFromBarcode(_barcode, IDClienteValue);
            String Message = getActivity().getString(R.string.ArticleDetailDialog_txt).replace("[DESCRIZIONE]", articleName);
            final AlertDialog.Builder confermInserimentoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            // confermInserimentoDialog.setView(R.id.layoutConfermaInserimento);
            confermInserimentoDialog.setTitle("Attenzione");
            confermInserimentoDialog.setCancelable(false);
            confermInserimentoDialog.setMessage(Message)

                    .setPositiveButton("Aggiungi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            if (mAvanzamentoDoc == ProductsFragment2.k_AVANZAMENTO_DOC_APERTO_BOZZA) {
                                MethodsProducts.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantitaClick(context, viewHolder.btnAggiungiUnitaQuantita, viewHolder.btnQuantitaSelezionata, position, getItem(position), AdapterMode, savedAdapter, null, mSoggetto, mAvanzamentoDoc, IDDocumento, list);
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Aggiunto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                productsAdapter.Call_notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Annulla", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Articolo non aggiunto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = confermInserimentoDialog.create();
            alert.show();

            MethodsProducts.SettingDetailOrderRow(getActivity(),ProductsAdapter.mCaller,ProductsAdapter.mProductView, ProductsAdapter.savedAdapter.getItem(ProductsAdapter.getPosition(_barcode, getActivity())), ProductsAdapter.IDDocumento, 1, ProductsAdapter.myPosition,ProductsAdapter.mSoggetto,ProductsAdapter.mAvanzamentoDoc, null);

            new ProductsAdapter.setRowProductAsync(getActivity(),ProductsAdapter.mProductView, ProductsAdapter.myPosition,ProductsAdapter.holder, ProductsAdapter.savedAdapter.getItem(ProductsAdapter.myPosition),ProductsAdapter.mSoggetto, ProductsAdapter.IDDocumento,ProductsAdapter.mAvanzamentoDoc, null, ProductsAdapter.row).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);



        }
    }
}
```

My target is to make a confirm dialog where if user click "Confirm" button I add the barcode to the order. In a first step I used my "OpenConfirmDilalog" in getView method of adapter but it doesn't work well because my dialog appears 9 times. The method which add the barcode is "MethodsProducts.AggiungiUnitaQuantita". Principally my problem is that when I scan same article the application doesn't put it in the same row with quantity = 2 but in two different rows and I want they are in the same. I see that the problem is in the passing of viewholder. I need that the code is run when the form open.

I'm sorry if could be incoerence in the code but:
a) I'm new in the language and android studio
b) I deleted commented code

P.s: sorry for my english also

Thanks if you help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

will work only if you changed the data(`this.mItems`), but cannot see there have codes to modify the data.

Comment: Yes,  probably I deleted because it is useless for the problem or because I make a mistake to delete. Trying to find a solution, I choose to make a method in Adapter which add barcode but since I want that method is call on form opening, I'm putting it in GetView() which is called 5 times but I don't know where... I think that if I take off unless call for me, the programm has to be able to do what I want, not true?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved removing ViewHolder parameters and saving data first in local database and refreshing ListView